# E_VW1035 Cannot connect to Vectorwise server

Tags: ingres, vectorwise

I started with vectorwise, i try to create database but i can do this.

```
ingres@xx:~$ createdb essai
```

I have an error :

```
Creating database 'essai'. . .
E_VW1035 Cannot connect to Vectorwise server.
(Mon Jun 17 09:01:01 2013)
Creation of database 'essai' abnormally terminated.
```

So how i can resolve this error ? and how i can drop database ? because when i retry

```
ingres@xx:~$ createdb essai
```

I see essai exist already

```
Creating database 'essai'. . .
E_DU3021_DB_EXISTS_CR
The database, essai, already exists. 
Creation of database 'essai' abnormally terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Vectorwise is available at docu.actian.com

Here you will find references to all of the commands you can use.

To answer the second question first.  If you know you can destroy the database then :

destroydb dbname

will do this for you.

If this is a new installation of Vectorwise - try looking in the vectorwise.log file in $II_SYSTEM/ingres/files ( or on Windows down the C:\ProgramData\Actian path ).

You will find an error condition here. In this case if you server is under configured this will be due to insufficient resources - most likely RAM.

If this is the case then you will need to either add more physical RAM to this server (4GB is the minimum recommended) or update the vecvtorwise .conf file to reduce the memory requirements (this would be for a dev/test ONLY solution!)

If this is not your problem - please post the error you see.
If it is the solution you need please update this post.

Comment: For resolve the problem, you need to execute: **root@xx:~#  apt-get install libaio1** after when you execute createdb essai, you obtain : Creating database 'essai' . . .
 
Creating DBMS System Catalogs . . .
Modifying DBMS System Catalogs . . .
Creating Standard Catalog Interface . . .
Creating Front-end System Catalogs . . .

Creation of database 'essai' completed successfully.